# sqlite number format exception not working

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using a sqlite database in my android application. In my Employee table there are three fields `"emp_id","ph no","address"` with data type integer, integer and text.  emp_id is the primary key. If I entered string for `"emp_id"` and try to insert into table then it gives number format exception wich is correct but for "ph no". If I enter the string value then it is not throwing an exception, it's accepting it.

Here is my piece of code:

```
}else{
    sqlcon.open();
    try {
        sqlcon.insert(DisaplayTables_list.getTableNameFromListView, storeEditextText);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"column value already exists",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    System.out.println("size of storeEdittext=" + storeEditextText.size());
    System.out.println("size of Edit Texts: " + allEds.size());

}

Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DisplayTable_Grid.class);
startActivity(i);
sqlcon.close();

}
```

Comment: what is the data type of phone?and emp id?

Comment: second thing if empid is primary key ?is it autoincreament? if yes then why your trying to insert it thruogh your code cause if it is autoincreament then system automatically will increase it


if still you want to enter it through your program then make sure it is in number format

Comment: yes emp_id and phone both are integer type.my issue is with "phone"  why it is accepting string value even its datatype is integer .

Comment: sqllite provide such kind of functionality datatype doesnt matter for it

Comment: see my answer hope it wll clear your doubts

Answer (score 0):

**SQLite lets me insert a string into a database column of type integer!**

This is a feature, not a bug. SQLite uses dynamic typing. It does not enforce data type constraints. Data of any type can (usually) be inserted into any column. You can put arbitrary length strings into integer columns, floating point numbers in boolean columns, or dates in character columns. The datatype you assign to a column in the CREATE TABLE command does not restrict what data can be put into that column. Every column is able to hold an arbitrary length string. (There is one exception: Columns of type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY may only hold a 64-bit signed integer. An error will result if you try to put anything other than an integer into an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column.)

But SQLite does use the declared type of a column as a hint that you prefer values in that format. So, for example, if a column is of type INTEGER and you try to insert a string into that column, SQLite will attempt to convert the string into an integer. If it can, it inserts the integer instead. If not, it inserts the string. This feature is called type affinity.

[Click here for refference](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q3)

hope it clear all your doubts happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature, not a bug. SQLite uses dynamic typing. It does not enforce data type constraints. Data of any type can (usually) be inserted into any column. You can put arbitrary length strings into integer columns, floating point numbers in boolean columns, or dates in character columns. The datatype you assign to a column in the CREATE TABLE command does not restrict what data can be put into that column. Every column is able to hold an arbitrary length string. (There is one exception: Columns of type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY may only hold a 64-bit signed integer. An error will result if you try to put anything other than an integer into an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column.)

But SQLite does use the declared type of a column as a hint that you prefer values in that format. So, for example, if a column is of type INTEGER and you try to insert a string into that column, SQLite will attempt to convert the string into an integer. If it can, it inserts the integer instead. If not, it inserts the string. This feature is called type affinity.

Comment: but can you tell me what should i do if i do not want to insert string value in integer type